# OpenSMTP: Debugging "mta error reason=AUTH rejected: 535 Authentication failed"

Tags: email, smtp, openbsd

I’m setting up an email relay on my OpenBSD server.
I followed the example on the smtpd.conf man page
https://man.openbsd.org/smtpd.conf

```
touch /etc/mail/secrets

chmod 640 /etc/mail/secrets

chown root:_smtpd /etc/mail/secrets

echo "bob username:password" > /etc/mail/secrets

smtpd.conf would look like this:

table aliases file:/etc/mail/aliases

table secrets file:/etc/mail/secrets

listen on lo0

action "local" mbox alias <aliases>

action "relay" relay host smtp+tls://bob@smtp.example.com auth <secrets>

match for local action "local"

match for any action "relay"
```

When I try to send an email it gets stuck in the mail queue
with a “Network error on destination MXs” message.

When I run “smtpd -dv” and try to send an email I get the following error:

mta error reason=AUTH rejected: 535 Authentication failed

I’m able to connect and send mail to the SMTP server with Thunderbird on a client system,
so I’m guessing this is a local configuration issue.